# How to alter the visual behavior of a ListViewItem in UWP?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, win-universal-app

In UWP, every time a `ListViewItem` is selected, a storyboard is triggered to give the user the feeling the component is reacting to the pressure of a touch. That storyboard also changes the `ListViewItem`'s background color until it gets released.

I have designed a `UserControl` which uses a `ListView` internally but would like to override this behavior as it doesn't really fit the application's proposed design.

Bellow are the `VisualStateGroups` I tried to apply both to the `ListView` through its `ControlTemplate` and to `ListViewItem` through its `DataTemplate` definition as the former attempt failed.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
        <VisualState x:Name="UnFocused" />
        <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver" />
        <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Selecting" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Selected" />
        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping" />
        <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused" />
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

One possibility could be to bind the root grid of the `DataTemplate` to the `ItemsContainer` so that I could override the default behavior every time an item was selected. But I am not that versed in XAML and couldn't figure out the proper way of doing this by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time, but in the end it was simpler than expected. I just had to add a `ControlTemplate` targeting the `ListViewItem`, which I didn't before as I was stuck fiddling with the `ControlTemplate` of the `ListView`.

As we do not declare the `ListViewItem` directly, the way is to use `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`. The final result is as follows:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

As you can see, an empty `ListViewItemPresenter` is good enough to override most of the default behavior. I couldn't get rid of the pressing animation, but I'm happy with the current results.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the `ListViewItemPresenter` as I am sure you have discovered. And, I am sure you have discovered that it is not template-able. The purpose of this more encapsulated approach is purely performance. As a result, items in a ListView are measurably faster to render. However, it does mean that when you want to change it, you are sort of stuck. Does it mean you cannot change it to use your own presenter and unwind the performance improvements? Does it mean you will have a lot of custom code? Yes. Does it means it is not possible? No. Does it mean it is a good idea? Well. I don't know how to answer that one. But, at least you know why it appears to be a brick wall.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? Don't see details like that in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.listviewitempresenter